# IIF query expression using Like "*" for the True condition

Tags: ms-access

I have a database which tracks employee QA. I'd like to be able to search by a single Staff Member, a whole team, or a Unit. I have three controls that correspond to those fields and only one can ever have a value at once. In my quesry I'd like to have threee expressions that will limit my results by one of those three fields. I'm adding just one to start and I've hit a problem.

I found this https://www.acuitytraining.co.uk/microsoft-training-courses/access/if-statements/ which seems to do what I want. Here is the code I'm trying.

```
IIf(IsNull([Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![cmbStaffSelect]), 
[UserLogin] Like "*",[UserLogin]=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu]. 
[Form]![cmbStaffSelect])
```

Which works fine if the control has a value. (condition is false) If the dropdown has no value (condition is true) I get zero results. I suspect the problem lies with the Like  "*" on my UserLogin field. Here is my query wizard and the buildler wizard for the IIF expression
[image: A picture of the query wizard]

Can anyone see why I'm not getting any results for the dropdown control being empty. To my thinking this should give me an unfiltered list of results. I have double checked my data and there are 137 records that should appear if I'm not limited by the staff selection.

The short version of this is if cmbStaffSelect has a value I want my records limited by that value. If cmbStaffSelect is blank I want to get all records.

Comment: Use a WHERE clause in your query instead. Like `WHERE [UserLogin] = [Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![cmbStaffSelect] OR [Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![cmbStaffSelect] Is Null`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know SQL really. Would I put this whole statement in as an expression in the query builder, or would I put it in as two criteria under the field UserLogin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the `iif` function will always evaluate **both** the *then* **and** *else* arguments, before returning the appropriate value depending on the value returned when evaluating the supplied test expression.

As such, if either the *then* or *else* arguments have the potential to error when evaluated (regardless of the result of the evaluation of the test expression), then the `iif` expression has the potential to error.

As an alternative, you could use the `Nz` function to achieve the same result:

```sql
[UserLogin] LIKE Nz([Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![cmbStaffSelect],"*")
```

Comment: For some others that might happen upon this - I also had a problem with cmbStaffSelect being  = "" instead of being NULL. Once I corrected that this method worked a treat. Thank you very much for the alternate method.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your IsNull([Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![cmbStaffSelect]) is always returning false because cmbStaffSelect might be equal to empty string?

Try something like this:
IIf(Trim([Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![cmbStaffSelect] & "") = "", 
[UserLogin] Like "*",[UserLogin]=[Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu]. 
[Form]![cmbStaffSelect])

This checks to see if the cmbStaffSelect is "" ... if cmbStaffSelect is null - it converts it to "" by appending an "" to the null value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your hunch is exactly correct.  If you want your query result to return the * symbol for the UserLogin field; then alter your IIF statement to be: [UserLogin] = "*"

Comment: I don't want it to return the * as the criteria, I want there to be no criteria at all if the control is blank. What I want is to be able to sometimes select a particular team when I see the records. Other times I want to see the entire dataset. My problem is if I have a value in the cmbStaffSelect it works fine, I see just that team member. If there is no value in cmbStaffSelect I get no results. What I want to get is ALL results, unlimited by staff name.

Comment: Well a 'calculated field' returns a value in that field.  Thus your IIF statement can only return a value of THIS or THAT.

Comment: I was thinking this was a 'calculated field' returns a value in that field.  If instead you are attempting to an IIF statement in the criteria - try this instead: I'll call it Field X that has the criteria.  Have that field twice in the query (the second one must have an alias name)  In the first put your criteria: [Forms]![MainMenu]![btnManagersMenu].[Form]![cmbStaffSelect]), 
[UserLogin]          ------------------------- In the second field X criteria, in the next criteria line (which means it is an OR statement) - leave the criteria blank.    See if this approach gives you what you seek.